# How to add a class to first html element in my case?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am using angular framework for my app.

I wanted to add a class to only the first element of my ng-repeat.

```
<div class='onlyFirst' ng-repeat = 'task in tasks'>{{task.chore}}</div>
```

However, the above code will apply to all my div and I only need first div having the `onlyFirst` class. Is there anyway to do it?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
ng-class="{onlyFirst : $first}"
```

So your code could look like this:

```
<div ng-repeat = 'task in tasks'>
    <div ng-class="{onlyFirst : $first}">{{task.chore}}</div>
</div>
```

Reference:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-class and with the $first variable which is available in a ng-repeat.

```
<div  
   ng-repeat = 'task in tasks' 
   ng-class="{onlyFirst:'$first'}"
   >{{task.chore}}</div>
```

Related docs:

- http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat
- http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply specific CSS to only the first child, you could also leverage CSS' first child selector:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp